# browser debug tools

Tags: dapp-debugging

I found it really painful to debug data flow between dapp and rpcnode im talking to. I have to search over network tab in chrome dev tools, manually decode data (when know abi ... ). When it comes to more fancy testing like mocking errors I have to rely or some http proxies. I was searching over the web and no help. Isnt there some browser extension like react devtools that one can install and see in developer console in browser like tones of other similar debug tools? It sounds impossible, but maybe?

Comment: Did you try using ganache as test network?

Comment: Of course im using ganache but this is not the case. Im talking about the case when I connected to real network and I want to properly inspect communication with blockchain. Currently there is no tool to do that.